# How to do binary conditional rendering lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, conditional, template, dynamic-design-attributes-rendering

I have created a lightning web component to show several related object tables on a detailpage. Above one of the tables I want to show some extra specific data related to one of the object tables.

We can use `<template if:true={display}>`. Since I am using the same component on the same page. On rendering 1 specific component I would like to show extra data.

Is there a binary rendering condition to achieve this? Something like:

```
<template if:true={{object}=='Contact'}>
```

I thought of a boolean as property on the component but then if I would like to show other data for another table I would still have to Identify which table. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will want to use a getter in order to compute an expression and return a boolean value. For ex.

js file

```
get verifySomething() {
        return prop.object === 'Contact'
    }
```

template

```
<template if:true={verifySomething}>
```

Comment: So binary rendering is not possible?

Comment: you cant evaluate expression in templates as you could in AURA